# How can I get rid of the grub menu on Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: grub2

I am rather new to the Ubuntu OS. Everything was running smoothly for a few days, then this menu came up. I don't remember exactly, but it won't let me enter the OS. I've never been that big on programming and computers and other stuff, so I don't know how to get past this. It says "grub>" and I've tried entering my Ubuntu username and Password, but I still can't get past the screen. Help me please?

Comment: What message appears before the `grub>` prompt?

Answer (score 2):

What you are noticing is broken grub. Grub is a bootloader, essentially what it does is load your operating system after your BIOS/EFI. When you get the

> grub>

it means grub didn't find the configuration file for your OS. You can largely use this answer to fix it: 
[How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)